# Is there a way to remove Options http method from a third party web app

Tags: http, proxy, webserver, pass-through

I have a web app created by someone else which is hosting APIs, now it's getting flagged by our security team as it exposes the OPTIONS http method and I have no control to disable it.

So am thinking of putting something in front of the web app which can block request for OPTIONS but allow the rest.

I tried ngnix stream but it's not helping, also proxypass just redirects to original api.